# Excel -VBA+API - Most performant solution to add a column and have historical data from daily API

Tags: excel, vba, api, automation

This is an overall question, meaning I'd like to discuss the best way to solve the problem, instead of going technical on the code.

Here's the description of what I would like to build.

***Actual Situation***

Using an issue tracker, I call an API and get all the data from a tracker query. 
IE, in redmine, or JIRA, I create a query, save it, and then via API I am able to import the data in a worksheet. 
This is ok now, and I created infographics and dashboard which updates every 30 minutes. 
Smooth.

***Evolution***

The data from API are saved in a worksheet called "DATA".
There's a field, call it "% Done" which should be changing at least every end of the day. 
When the API updates the query, the field is updated in the "Data" Worksheet correctly.

What I need is a worksheet in which, from this query or another (that makes no difference), 
I have this kind of mockup :

```
+---------+------------+
| issue # | 20/01/2020 |
+---------+------------+
|   23415 | 10%        |
+---------+------------+
```

When the API updates the data, IF THE date is the new day, here's what happens :

```
+---------+------------+------------+
| issue # | 20/01/2020 | 21/01/2020 |
+---------+------------+------------+
|   23415 | 10%        | 20%        |
+---------+------------+------------+
```

And obviously if the %Done is not changing, the third day I will have the table with :

```
+---------+------------+------------+------------+
| issue # | 20/01/2020 | 21/01/2020 | 22/01/2020 |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+
|   23415 | 10%        | 20%        | 20%        |
+---------+------------+------------+------------+
```

The date is TODAY(), as the API is called once per day, and is written in the header cell. 
The %Done is reloaded every day, and what I would like to talk about is the most performant way to 
have maybe 20k  records all updated, with 20k row per call.

Any suggestions on how to achieve the best results, more on a "Architectural" side ?

Thank you all, if you need more informations about, just ask.

CG.

Answer (score 0):

There is a significant overhead each time VBA calls Excel to get data and an even larger overhead every time VBA calls Excel to put data onto a sheet. Therefore the most performant way is to minimise the number of calls by maximising the amount of data transferred in each call.

In practice this means using arrays to read as large a block of data as possible and caching stuff retrieved from your API into an array and then writing the array back as infrequently as possible.

Comment: Right, I was thinking about that, and I agree with you.
The fact is, this task should be performed once a day, and the API should be called to get only 2 columns (ie, issue# and %Done as per my example). 
The number of record should be lower than what I wrote, I should reduce it to 200 rows.
Than means that in this way, the quantity of data and the effort should be not that much.

I am actually working on an API call that is recalling 20k records for almost 15 columns, and ( without VBA and columns added ), it takes almost 3 seconds to update.